# SQL: Difference between consecutive rows

Tags: sql, datetime, hive, window-functions, datediff

Table with 3 columns: order id, member id, order date

[image]

Need to pull the distribution of orders broken down by No. of days b/w 2 consecutive orders by member id

What I have is this:

```
SELECT 
  a1.member_id,
  count(distinct a1.order_id) as num_orders, 
  a1.order_date, 
  DATEDIFF(DAY, a1.order_date, a2.order_date) as days_since_last_order
from orders as a1 
inner join orders as a2 
  on a2.member_id = a1.member_id+1;
```

It's not helping me completely as the output I need is:

[image]

Comment: What is the logic to compute `num_orders`? I don't get it.

Comment: Sorry, that is count()

Comment: What is the logic? For example, for customer `22222`, how do you get `2` for orders `1212` and `1215`, and `1` for the two following orders?

Comment: It's order_id for an item type. A person can order 2 quantities of the same item, like 2 coffees. Order_id for coffee would be the same, example: 138 but num_orders would 2

Comment: But that is not mandatory, what I want to calculate is "days since last order" column by member_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to get the date of the previous order by the same customer:

```
select o.*,
    datediff(
        order_date,
        lag(order_date) over(partition by member_id order by order_date, order_id)
    ) days_diff
from orders o
```

When there are two rows for the same date, the smallest `order_id` is considered first. Also note that I fixed your `datediff()` syntax: in Hive, the function just takes two dates, and no unit.

I just don't get the logic you want to compute `num_orders`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, I am new to lag function so was trying self join. Your query actually helped, it works. I think I will calculate num_orders on top of this query/table

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```
SELECT 
  a1.member_id,
  count(distinct a1.order_id) as num_orders, 
  a1.order_date, 
  DATEDIFF(DAY, a1.order_date, a2.order_date) as days_since_last_order
from orders as a1 
inner join orders as a2 
  on a2.member_id = a1.member_id
where not exists (
      select intermediate_order
      from orders as intermedite_order 
      where intermediate_order.order_date < a1.order_date and intermediate_order.order_date > a2.order_date) ;
```